# Design table Relation N to N in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I design this table for relation between news and tags, please help me...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newstag` (
  `idnews` int(10) unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
  `idtag` int(10)  unsigned PRIMARY KEY,
    FOreign Key('idnews') References news('id'), 
    FOreign Key('idtag') References tag('idtag')
)   ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
>       to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''idnews') References
>       news('id'), FOreign Key('idtag') References tag('idta' at line 4

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: This query has error!!!

Comment: So, post the error. No one here can guess what it is, right?

Comment: In addition to that error, you have a multiple PK defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE news(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE tag(idtag INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `newstag` (
    ->   `idnews` int NOT NULL,
    ->   `idtag` int NOT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (idnews,idtag),
    ->     Foreign Key (idnews) References news(id),
    ->     Foreign Key (idtag) References tag(idtag)
    -> )   ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```